# Django REST Framework return a pdf without using database

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create Django REST API. It should get data via **POST** request and based on that data it should create a pdf(using xhtml2pdf). It should be a simple project, so I'd like not to include a database, and that is the question, is it possible to do it without a database(the request will contain dates, strings, and arrays).

Comment: Yes if you dont need any further values you can do it without a db. What have you tried so far? try writing a python script with a function that takes data and creates a pdf once you are there try to imp,ement this function into views.py and connect it to a url.

Comment: I've already created that function in views.py but currently I've loaded dates from a dictionary in views.py, how can I implement that api structure into views, how should I create a model in models.py?

Comment: ```class ViewPDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        pdf = render_to_pdf('html_to_pdf/pdf_template.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')``` it's my current code (data - dictionary)

Comment: Please add your views.py and show us the relevant code. What have you tried, does an error accure? please dont poste code in the comments, edit your question.